# Reproducing Ruby OpenSSL private_encrypt output in C#

Tags: c#, ruby, encryption, openssl, rsa

I have a simple Ruby script that I am using to do a private_encrypt on some HTTP headers to sign a web request that is to be sent to a ruby REST API, the API tests the Base64 encoded string against a Base64 encoded string it generates rather than decoding the Base64 and decrypting the data then testing the original string.

The script I am using is

```
require "openssl"
require "base64"

path_to_cert = ARGV[0].dup

plain_text = Base64.decode64(ARGV[1].dup)

private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(path_to_cert))

puts Base64.encode64(private_key.private_encrypt(plain_text))
```

The fact that the input is Base64 encoded is purely due to linebreaks and spaces in the input argument.

To use this I am having to shell out to ruby using System.Diagnostics.Process and capture the StdOut, while this isn't a major problem and works I'd like to remove the dependency on ruby but I am unable to reproduce the output using the C# RsaCryptoServiceProvider.

If I Base64 Encode the private_encrypt result of "SimpleString" using ruby i consistently get

> auReJzoPSW3AhzsfT3EH4rD7lc4y2CJ026xIOiV6kjl2OKIj8GnzrPosoJDg\nSHrvLVKrSxYlegYgJRMx+vaAHSAm7RXrZh5An2SnVuO3qITa2TJ78hTc3bAw\nCDm4i9/4qictjxEFfnPRe6
>   EYCa4b3dnM5moa1eo9zbQPBa1eS6ItRCX4C0G0\n1tJpQsEvuums363eAhTUAYa6yEWuINLPmE0USW6jfFNnsxw8Nv9SnC+ziomb\n/mwlt9dS5/mzKM8yFMH6hdQYLoqc0QpjT+xaZ1ZyJ6dG5MVG
>   h3JtjIVRTOSd\n+pUU/bo+obEHbrftG8u2uJImLSA+/1e8aapHaa3WNg==

When using the .Net

```
RsaCryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt("SimpleString", false)
```

The result is always a different output due to the fact it is encrypting with the public key.

I have also tried

```
RsaCryptoServiceProvider.SignData
```

and while this always yields the same result, it is different to the result from ruby.

Can I use some CryptoAPI directly from .Net that will allow me to achieve the same result as Ruby?

Comment: Do you just want to use the BCL? Because you could probably do it with BouncyCastle. AFAIK there's no way to use the private key to encrypt in the BCL. SignData creates a hash of the data, not meant for decryption.

Comment: I wanted to but I had pretty much come to the conclusion that using the BCL wasn't going to happen, as long as the solution is all .Net based and removes the dependency on shelling out to Ruby then 3rd party components are fine. I'll have a look into Bouncy Castle! Thanks.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have been trying to recreate CHEF rest calls in C#, would you? Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

What you require is a method of generating "raw signatures". Raw signatures generally consist of modular exponentiation of PKCS#1 v1.5 compatible signature formats, although other padding methods may be used as well. The difference with a normal signing operation is that it *does not* perform any hashing, and - in the case of PKCS#1 v1.5 compatible signature formats - does not create the ASN.1 structure around the hash value, which is used to identify the hashing method used.

This *raw signature formats* are not a standardized method of generating signatures and *should be avoided*. `private_encrypt` mainly is used to support deprecated versions of SSL, that uses the method to create a signature for authentication using a concatenation of the raw output of MD5 and SHA1 hash values.

Finally, as Siva suggested, you may use the Bouncy Castle C# libraries to create raw signature formats. The raw signature format is not supported out of the box by most higher level API's, for the reasons given in the second paragraph.

[EDIT2] To accomplish this you need to use the raw "RSA" functionality.

```
if (mechanism.Equals("RSA"))
{
    return (new RsaDigestSigner(new NullDigest()));
}
```

After that the `RsaDigestSigner` class will use the `EncodeBlock` method in `DigestInfo` to generate the PKCS#1 padding. The `NullDigest` does not do nothing, it just returns the data given to it as signature of itself.

Comment: Answer is somewhat late, I'm just going through some back log of older questions...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [Bouncy Castle C#](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/)? It provides complete framework for cryptography and there is class to load X509Certificate from PEM file.

Comment: Although using using Bouncy is always a good idea to use perform lower level cryptography API, I think this answer does not sufficiently tackle the given question.

Answer (score -1):

You can encrypt using the private key.

Here's at least one example of doing it:

http://www.csharpbydesign.com/2008/04/asymmetric-key-encryption-with.html

Note the use of the PrivateKey property when doing the encryption (although the article references *decryption*, you can do the same with encryption as well)

Comment: I've tried many different samples and the RSACryptoServiceProvider isn't capable of doing what I require, it can only sign using the private key not encrypt and the sign creates a hash and encrypts that which gives a different output to what is required.  Not to mention I have had no luck loading the PEM file using RSACryptoServiceProvider or X509Certificate(2) I have had to implement this by loading the file at byte level manually!

Comment: This does not work, this will use the PKCS#1 v1.5 format used for encryption, not for signing.